# como hacer para que todo el template de overleaf tenga letra en color negro?

Tags: latex

tengo una duda. quiero que el template de overleaf este todo el texto entero en color negro pero no encuentro la linea de codigo que hace esto en el template que tengo:
https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl. ninguna linea que pongo me saca los colores rojo y bordo que aparecen .alguna idea ?
grcias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con el paquete `\usepackage{xcolor}`, mencionado en la [documentacion](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Using_colours_in_LaTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
This example shows some instances of using the \texttt{xcolor} package 
to change the colour of elements in \LaTeX.

\begin{itemize}
\color{blue}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{itemize}

\noindent
{\color{red} \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\end{document}
```

El resultado seria como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]